# Can use Cluster instead AeronCluster?

Tags: aeron

hi what's the difference between below method ? can use Cluster.offer() replace AeronCluster.offer() if offer() operation is on the same JVM process ?

io.aeron.cluster.client.AeronCluster.offer()

io.aeron.cluster.service.Cluster.offer()

I am expect a help, ths

Answer (score 0):

`AeronCluster.offer` is designed for cluster external use from a single threaded client. `Cluster.offer` is for use within the cluster and only from a service running in the service container. Using either of these from another thread can result in corrupt data. Using `Cluster.offer` from outside a `ClusteredService` can additionally cause node divergence in the cluster. If you don't know what that means then simply take that it is bad.